# How to create a block to show a digital clock?

Tags: blocks

I need to create a block to show a LIVE digital clock?

I tried to use the http://drupal.org/project/clock and the http://drupal.org/project/jstimer  modules but it doesn't use javascript to refresh the time, it shows the time when the page is load, to refresh the time I need to reload the page.

How can I do this?

Something like this http://drupal.org/project/timeblock but for D7

Comment: have you looked at how simple the timeblock module is and how easily it could be incorporated into a/your D7 site?

Comment: (although its use of a body element is puzzling/troublesome :)

Comment: Amazing what one can find when you start peeking in 3rd party code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

100% agree with Jimajamma above on extracting the stuff you need from the timeblock module, all it is really doing is just adding two javascript blocks with a minimal amount of formatting. For example, to replicate the 24-hour clock, all you have to do is create a new block with an 'unformatted' input format and add this code (extracted from the time block module):

```
<span id="liveclock" style="position:relative;left:0;top:0;">
</span>

<script language="JavaScript">
<!--

function show5(){
 if (!document.layers&&!document.all&&!document.getElementById)
 return
 var Digital=new Date()
 var hours=Digital.getHours()
 var minutes=Digital.getMinutes()
 var seconds=Digital.getSeconds()
 if (hours<12)
 hours="0"+hours
 if (minutes<=9)
 minutes="0"+minutes
 if (seconds<=9)
 seconds="0"+seconds
myclock="<strong>"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+"</strong>"
if (document.layers){
document.layers.liveclock.document.write(myclock)
document.layers.liveclock.document.close()
}
else if (document.all)
liveclock.innerHTML=myclock
else if (document.getElementById)
document.getElementById("liveclock").innerHTML=myclock
setTimeout("show5()",1000)
 }

$(document).ready(function(){ show5(); });


//-->
</script>
```

Quick fix to replace the body unload with a jquery $(document).ready() call, though probably not necessary inside a block.

Comment: yep, and fix the formatting bug still found in the original code: `if (hours<12)` should be `if (hours<=9)` so you have 01-09 but not 011 or 010 :)

Comment: yeah. Nice catch ;)